How to store a HashMap as separate item in the data storage on TON blockchain
In order to better serialize a contract's data I want to store a HashMap as separate item. In this case I'm trying to store a list of addresses. Here is what I'm trying:
(int, slice, slice, cell) load_data() inline {
  var ds = get_data().begin_parse();

  return (
    ds~load_msg_addr(), ;; sender address
    ds~load_msg_addr(), ;; owner address
    ds~load_uint(32), ;; index value
    ds~load_ref() ;; dictionary
  );
}

() save_data(int index, slice sender_address, slice owner_address) impure inline {
  cell dict = new_dict();

  dict~udict_set(256, index, sender_address);

  set_data(
    begin_cell()
    .store_slice(sender_address)
    .store_slice(owner_address)
    .store_uint(index, 32)
    .store_ref(dict)
    .end_cell()
  );
}

When I try to load the data, I get the following error
Unable to execute get method. Got exit_code: 9

Which accoring the documentation means:

9 - Compute Phase - Cell underflow. Read from slice primitive tried to read more bits or references than there are.

I've tried storing the Hashmap in different ways by using sotre_dict instead of store_ref and others, but couldn't figure out how to do it

I implemented it using this dict_set_slice_int function.
With this function, I stored user wallet address and his amount.
Please check this code snippet.
dict_set_slice_int(storage::is_claimed, 267, sender_address, claim_amount, 120);

If you have any questions, let me know at any time.
